# how to add details to google place which is added from my app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have added my place (new place added to one of supported type of Google API)to Google places from my app referred my link [Add new place to Google Places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493283/add-new-place-to-google-places).  Google places API having it's details such as formatted address,phone no,URL..etc. so now i also want to add details of that place,such as formatted address,phone number,url of place which added by me.

anyone please help me for this problem.